# how do we use mysqli properly to fetch all the records from table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting only one row, can someone please tell me how to get all the data from the table column of my database table ?

```
   public function getCategories(){
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM newscat');
    $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
               $rows[] = $row;
               return $rows;
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

You're returning from within the loop. That will break it in the first round.

`return` outside the loop.

Comment: there's a problem, the first row's id is being return as 0 , and not the real id from the table `foreach($cat->getCategories() as $key => $val){
        echo $val."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='editcat' href='edit.php?id=".$key."'>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='deletecat' href='delete.php?id=".$key."'>Delete</a><br />";
}`

Answer (score 2):

do the minor change

```
public function getCategories(){
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM newscat');
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `return $rows;`. It should reside *after* the `while`. The thing is that it will enter the while, put the first row in the array, and then immediately return it. What you want is to let the `while` do its thing, and *after* the it finished, return the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli. 
Then you can use its apiFfetch_all to get all the rows at once.

For example : 
**$array=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);**

The above code will get all associated rows in the corresponding array.