# preparing a private message system

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on preparing a private message system

the problem is here and now that it will only show one even though there are 4 into the database.

I want it to display all 4 at once, not just one of them.

The problem can be seen here

http://billedeupload.dk/?v=rXFTj.png

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, datoTime, checkpm FROM pm WHERE til=? ORDER BY datoTime DESC";
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $til);
    $til = $_GET["id"];

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $datoTime, $checkpm);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

        if($count >= 1)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/img/besked/reply.png" alt="svar" id="beskedu"></td>
                <td><a href="/pm-set/<?php echo $id;?>/"><?php echo $title;?></a></td>
                <td>
                <?php
                if($checkpm == 0)
                {
                ?>
                <a href="/pm-set/<?php echo $id;?>/"><img src="/img/besked/ulase.png" alt="ulæst" id="beskedu"></a>
                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                <a href="/pm-set/<?php echo $id;?>/"><img src="/img/besked/lase.png" alt="læst" id="beskedu"></a>
                <?php   
                }
                ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo date("H:i - d, M - Y", strtotime($datoTime));?></td>
                <td>Slet</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <div id="error"><p>Ingen besked</p></div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
```

Comment: Your using fetch instead of fetchAll also you don't seem to be looping through the results

Comment: so I have to make a loop for it to work?

Comment: Yes otherwise you are just returning the last result. Also use $result->fetch_assoc() instead of fetch. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239391/how-do-we-use-mysqli-properly-to-fetch-all-the-records-from-table

Comment: @LiamSorsby i have try and its now work for me :(

Comment: Update your code so we can see?

Comment: @LiamSorsby sorry, I mean that I not only get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you read one line and then close the result.

You need to loop through the results reading and processing one line at a time and then only once you are done close the result.

Comment: how do you think I can do it?,

Comment: Look at some of the examples on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627763/php-and-mysqli-bind-parameters-using-loop-and-store-in-array